# Ordenar alfabéticamente lista desplegable

Tags: javascript, c#

Estoy creando mi propio sitio web en **C#**, y estoy tratando de ordenar el listado de nombres de algunas personas que obtengo desde la base de datos en orden alfabético (A - Z).

Dejo un [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fpuvh8en/) con un ejemplo de lo que llevo realizado y la función hecha en **javacript** con la cual cargo el listado de las personas en la lista desplegable

```js
function loadResponsable() {
    const url = document.getElementById("responsables").value;
    document.getElementById("AssignDiv").style.display = "block";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            const responsables = document.getElementById("ticketRespInput");

            for (let idx in data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(idx)) {
                    const option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.innerHTML = data[idx];
                    option.value = idx;
                    responsables.options.add(option);
                }
            }
        }
    });
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-group" name="asignar" id="AssignDiv">
                                    <label class="required-field" name="asignar" id="lblAssignDiv" for="ticketRespInput">Asignado a:</label>
                                    <select onchange="validate(this)" id="ticketRespInput" name="assigned" class="form-control form-control-user validateable" style="width: 100%; padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem; height: 50px;" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <option value="" disabled selected>Sin asignar</option>
                                    </select>                                  
                                </div>
```

Comment: Por favor, añade el código a la pregunta: si ese fiddle se elimina la pregunta dejará de tener sentido.

Comment: @PabloLozano revisa nuevamente la pregunta ya agregue mi código

Comment: y donde es que esta la funcion que ordena?

Comment: @gbianchi Esa es la función que necesito la que me ordene en orden alfabético de A-Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con el siguiente código

```
function loadResponsable() {
    const url = document.getElementById("responsables").value;
    document.getElementById("AssignDiv").style.display = "block";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            const responsables = document.getElementById("ticketRespInput");

            const arrData = Object.keys(data).map(item => {
                return {
                    key: item,
                    value: data[item]
                }
            });

            const arrDataSorted = arrData.sort((a,b) => (a.value > b.value) ? 1 : ((b.value > a.value) ? -1 : 0));

            for (let idx in arrDataSorted) {
                const option = document.createElement("option");
                option.innerHTML = arrDataSorted[idx].value;
                option.value = arrDataSorted[idx].key;
                responsables.options.add(option);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Teniendo en cuenta que la respuesta que recibes desde la API es un objeto que contiene todo el diccionario (llave, valor) y no es un arreglo como tal, toca hacer un mapeo de esa respuesta para transformarlo a un array para después hacer uso del método sort() que incluyen los arreglos en javascript.

Comment: Probando tu posible solucion me presenta el siguiente error `Uncaught TypeError: data.sort is not a function`

Comment: La respuesta de la llamada ajax es un arreglo? en el código que hice asumí que es un arreglo dado que lo recorres. Sin embargo, el error que indicas me sugiere que no es un arreglo. En caso que si sea un arreglo prueba agregando Array.from(data).sort...

Comment: Puedes editar tu respuesta y dejarme el código detallado

Comment: Actualizada la respuesta

Comment: Probando con `Array.from(data).sort` ya no me muestra ningún dato en la lista desplegable

Comment: Podrías agregar en la pregunta cual es la respuesta de la API porque al ingresar al jsfiddle igual no me mostraba ningún item, por tanto asumí que de momento la respuesta era justamente un arreglo vacio pero en caso de devolver una respuesta valida, querías ordenar.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100991/discussion-between-sebastian-salazar-and-hamid-pinilla).